# what does this typescript function declaration with generics mean in trying to split an array into evens and odds

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have to write a function in Typescript to split the array into two arrays of evens and odds.

```
function evenAndOddArr<T>(arr: T[]): [T[], T[]] {...}
```

I am slightly confused as to what `<T>(arr: T[]): [T[], T[]]` this segment is referring to. I get that I am working with generics and I know how to split an array into evens and odds easily enough. What I don't understand specifically is how to return those two arrays back using T[] and T[].

Am I correct in assuming the two T[]s are the generic arrays that will be returned once properly split into evens and odds? If so, how would I call to them in the function itself?

Comment: `<T>(arr: T[]): [T[], T[]]` is a *call signature*.  It means that when you call a function with an array of type `T[]` (aka `Array<T>`), then the function will return a two-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where both the first and second elements will be arrays of type `T[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "how would I call to them in the function itself" means; could you rephrase?

Comment: I mean, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR52nW) is one way to implement your function, but I don't know which part of that constitutes an answer to the question (especially your last sentence which I don't understand).  Let me know how to proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, so I would just return a tuple in my function implementation containing the two arrays of evens and odds basically? to match with the call signature?

Comment: Yes.  So did these comments answer your question? If so I can write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this verbose approach makes it more clear:

```js
const evenAndOddArray<Item>(array: Array<Item>): [Array<Item>, Array<Item>] => // ...
```

Still, being a function that splits your array in a tuple of odds and evens, is better to just assume it will be numbers:

```js
const evenAndOddArray(array: Array<number>): [Array<number>, Array<number>] => // ...
// or
const evenAndOddArray(array: number[]): [number[], number[]] => // ...
```